# Изменение в отображении вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, кэширование

Сейчас заметил, что раньше мой вопрос появлялся в списке вопросов, только после двух просмотров. А сейчас вывалился сразу. Изменился алгоритм или репа влияет?

Comment: Нет, проделки кеша (:

Comment: @Suvitruf по правильному вопрос сразу виден должен быть?

Comment: Нет, он виден "через некоторое время". Просто иногда момент открытия списка вами совпадает с обновлением кеша, и вам кажется, что он сразу появился.

Comment: @Suvitruf, мне кажется, там хитрее с алгоритмом. А вот на странице [Вопросы](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions) должен быть виден сразу.

Comment: @Qwertiy иногда в вопросах раньше появляется, иногда на главной раньше. Там всё странно )

Comment: @Suvitruf, в вопросах вроде всегда раньше. Ну или одновременно.

Comment: @Qwertiy не, у меня было иначе. Я как-то даже тред создавал. Потом удалил, т.к. списал на кеш)